# Does Indian criminal law have provisions for post-conviction release from sentences?

Tags: indian-constitutional-law, indian-penal-code

I am researching the Indian penal system and it appears that the only provisions for this are Criminal Procedure Code (CrPC) Sections 360, 432, and 433. However, neither of these seem to apply to mandatory minimum sentences and there seems to be high administrative discretion. Are there any other provisions in addition to these?

Comment: What do you mean by "*post conviction release from sentences*"? Do you mean early release, say on probation for good behaviour, or something else?

Comment: this is late but parole.